# Why key of dictionary in Python can be same?

Tags: python

I am learning dictionary which is a data type in Python.

```
A={'color':'right','color':'wrong'}
print(A)
```

In the above code, keys are the same. I expect it should be wrong since in my opinion key should be unique, but it prints out {'color': 'wrong'}, which confuses me a lot.

Comment: What's confusing about it? It's as you say, keys must be unique, so in this case, the dictionary will contain only one key-value pair (the latter).

Comment: @PaulM. I am expecting it will report wrong

Comment: you are right that dictionary contains unique keys. If you define the same key twice, second value overrides the first value of that key

Comment: @PaulM. I don't know if Python guarantees to use the latter one, maybe it may choose any of those

Comment: @89085731 If you want to print the value associated with the key `color`, you need to do `print(A["color"])`.

Comment: @AlexLarionov It is [guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays).

Comment: Don't confuse the dictionary display that creates a `dict` with the `dict` itself. A key can be repeated any number of times in the display, but the value in the resulting `dict` will be that of the rightmost occurrence of the key.

Comment: @buran thanks. That really works

Comment: @Alex Larionov: Python didn't always guarantee the use of the latter one, but at some point that changed (likely as a result of some PEP being implemented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict` keys must be unique. If you reassign a key, the dictionary just deletes the existing entry before adding the new value.

```
>>> A = {'color':'right'}
>>> A
{'color': 'right'}
>>> A['color'] = 'wrong'
>>> A
{'color': 'wrong'}
```

That's what happened in your case

```
A={'color':'right','color':'wrong'}
```

The `'color', 'right'` key/value pair was set but it was deleted when the like keyed `'color', 'wrong'` pair was set afterwords. The same thing happens if you use the `dict` constructor

```
>>> A = dict([('color', 'right'), ('color', 'wrong')])
>>> A
{'color': 'wrong'}
```